# Facing issues while migrating Spring2.5.6 version to Spring4.1.4

Tags: java, spring, maven, migration

Hi We are in process of upgrading the spring web application built on spring2.5.6 version to spring 4.x. I am trying with spring4.1.4 when i specify that version in my POM.XML. It started throwing errors. One of the serious issue i am facing AbstractTransactionalSpringContextTests with this class and this class is deprecated in spring3.0 version. We are using this class for integration test. 
what approach do i need to follow to fix that issue.

AbstractTransactionalSpringContextTests  class is depricated in spring3.0. many classes inheriting the above class.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project xxxx: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] \Users\RB35168\IdeaProjects\RZMMigration\xxx\RollbackableSpringContextTest.java:[7,31] error: cannot find symbol

public abstract class RollbackableSpringContextTest extends AbstractTransactionalSpringContextTests {
```

Comment: That class doesn't exist anymore it was a JUnit3 base class and JUnit 3 isn't supported anymore in Spring 4.x. Move all your testcases to JUnit 4 and extend [`AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests `](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/junit4/AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests.html). Or first move to Spring 3.2 (that way all the classes are still there) move the code base (you can use most of the features) and as a last step move to JUnit4. That way your migration could be better controlled.

Comment: we are using TESTNG environment. What do you suggest weather to move directly with Spring 4.x or first upgrade to 3.2 and later goahead with spring 4.X

Comment: Didn't realize that, then extend the proper TestNG [`AbstractTransactionalTestNGSpringContextTests `](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/testng/AbstractTransactionalTestNGSpringContextTests.html) class as that old one has also been cleaned up. Either way the only supported way for testing is with annotations (`@Test` etc) and not the old class hierachy).